# adding an `ifelse` like statement or `trycatch` to code for reading in files

Tags: r

I am trying to read in some data using a combination of `list.files` etc.

I have a character value called `myfiles` and looks like the following;

```
[1] "E:/IRI Data/External/demos12.csv"
[2] "E:/IRI Data/External/demo8.CSV"  
[3] "E:/IRI Data/External/demos10.CSV"
[4] "E:/IRI Data/External/demos11.CSV"
[5] "E:/IRI Data/External/demos9.CSV"
```

Which has different font sizes for the `.csv` formats. I have the following function:

```
myfiles = lapply(myfiles,
                 FUN = function(files) {
                   read.csv(files, header = TRUE)
                 })
```

Which reads in the `.csv` files, however, I have some lowercase and some uppercase so I am running into errors on line 3 of that function `read.csv` - I am trying to expand the function such that if the file does not exits for `.csv` lowercase then try `.CSV` uppercase.

Any help would be great.

Comment: which of the files you want to read?  Do you want to avoid reading the `.csv` files?

Comment: Ah sorry, I am trying to read all of the files using this function. For a similar task I read all of the `.csv` lowercase and it stores them as a large list of 5 elements.

Comment: Where is the issue in reading these files?  Are you saying that 2:5 files are not reading

Comment: The issue is coming from the file extentions. The line `read.csv(files, header = TRUE)` is only able to read in lowercase `.csv` files so when an uppercase `.csv` file extention is thrown at it the function breaks.

Comment: EDIT: Wait something is working... I will update you ASAP.

Comment: Ok, so do you want to read it or just throw an exception?

Comment: Try `sub("\\.([^.]+)$", ".\\L\\1", myfiles, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: You can get the proper spelling of the files with `list.files()`